# How to do a very smooth second clock hand animation (without ticking motion) like the iPad clock

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer, clock

I am working on an iPad app where I am trying to show the clock hand for seconds show the second hand motion, like this which updated every second.

```
- (void) updateClock:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
    dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    seconds = [dateComponents second];
    minutes = [dateComponents minute];
    hours = [dateComponents hour];
    secAngle = Degrees2Radians(seconds/60.0*360);
    minAngle = Degrees2Radians(minutes/60.0*360);
    hourAngle = Degrees2Radians(hours/24.0*360) + minAngle/24.0;
    secHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (secAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
    hourHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (hourAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
    minHand.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation (minAngle+M_PI, 0, 0, 1);
}

- (void)start{
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateClock:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

However, the way its works right now, it shows like it is ticking every second. But What I really want is to animate the layer so that it appears to be in continuously motion in a full rotation from 0 to 360 in  1 minute smoothly , however, I can only make it start to go from 0 to 360 to do a full rotation ,so I used for the seconds needle the following:

```
-(void)startSmooth{
    started = YES;
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
    fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
    fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotation.duration = 60.0f;
    fullRotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [secHand addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
}
```

However the problem with this is that it always starts rotating at 0 degree angle so the needle looks like it only always appear to start motion from 30 seconds no matter what the time is.

What I would like to do is have it begin from the actual point the seconds needle is supposed to be at. How can I achieve that?

Comment: If the second hand rotates 360 degrees in one minute, it rotates 6 degrees in one second...

Comment: Using NSTimer is the wrong approach. Use Core Animation instead.

Comment: While I and others initially focused on the animation issue, I realize that part of your problem is that `NSDateComponents` does not handle fractions of a section (and thus regardless of how sophisticated your animation, you'll still get a ticking second hand vs a sweeping one. You need to get milliseconds. You could probably create a new `NSDate` from your date components and then look at the `timeIntervalSinceDate`, but easier is probably to just get the time components from a `NSDateFormatter` that you parse. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all, I found out the answer to my own question using the developer docs by using fromValue and byValue instead of fromValue and toValue

Just needed to change :

```
-(void)startSmooth{
    CABasicAnimation *fullRotationSec;
    fullRotationSec = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    fullRotationSec.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:secAngle+M_PI];
    fullRotationSec.byValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
    fullRotationSec.duration = 60.0f;
    fullRotationSec.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [secHandView addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two issues: Best way to animate and how to get milliseconds

#### Alternative to `NSTimer`-based animation

You might want to consider using a [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) rather than `NSTimer` or Core Animation.

First, you can create a `CADisplayLink` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
```

Second, you can set the display link and start it:

```
- (void)startDisplayLink
{
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(handleDisplayLink:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}
```

Third, you can then put your clock hand drawing logic here:

```
- (void)handleDisplayLink:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    // update your clock hands here
}
```

Finally, if you need to stop the display link, you can call:

```
- (void)stopDisplayLink
{
    [self.displayLink invalidate];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}
```

#### How to get milliseconds

While I initially thought you were focusing on the animation issue, but I realize the root of your issue is that `NSDateComponents` sadly does not do milliseconds. There are a bunch of ways of getting the milliseconds, but I might just use a date formatter:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"hh:mm:ss.SSS";
NSString *string = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSArray *timeComponents = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

// if time was 09:48:17.197, then

NSInteger hour = [timeComponents[0] integerValue];    // 9
NSInteger min = [timeComponents[1] integerValue];     // 48
CGFloat floatSec = [timeComponents[2] floatValue];    // 17.197
```

and if you want the hour and minute hands to sweep, just like the seconds hand, then you can calculate their fractional values, too:

```
CGFloat floatMin = min + (floatSec / 60.0);           // 48.287
CGFloat floatHour = hour + (floatMin / 60.0);         // 9.805
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered [this SO question about drawing a clock face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838371/how-to-rotote-the-hands-of-clock-for-the-24-hour-clock/14839464#14839464) based on a timer.  This animation can be run at any frequency (any level of "smoothness") depending on the interval of the timer that's used to call it.

See the calling code at the bottom:  just change the timer interval to something small, like 0.1 sec.